# Creating a csv file in the new thread using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I would like to create a csv file using a new thread.
Below is the code that I wrote:

```
import GPS_lib as GPS
import time
from threading import Thread
import csv

def GPSThread():
    try:
        GPS.gps=GPS.InitConnection()

        last_print_gps=time.time()
        with open(GPS.PATH,"w") as csvfile:
             fieldnames=['Time','Latitude','Longitude','Speed','CoG']
             writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)
             writer.writeheader()

             while True:
                  GPS.gps.update()
                  current_gps=time.time()
                  print(GPS.LATITUDE)
                  if current_gps-last_print_gps>=1:
                       last_print_gps=current_gps
                       GPS.GetGPSValues()     
                       writer.writerow({
                      'Time':GPS.TIME,
                      'Latitude':GPS.LATITUDE,
                      'Longitude': GPS.LONGITUDE,
                      'Speed': GPS.SPEED, 
                      'CoG': GPS.CoG})
    except:
         print("Error")


GPS_thread=Thread(target=GPSThread,args=())
GPS_thread.start()
GPS_thread.join()
```

If I use this code without new thread, everything works. With new thread I have only empty file. Why? Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve i.e. with meaninful code instead of *...* and with needed imports and some sample data, i.e. complete code+data that I could paste into a file and run to examine the problem you have.

Comment: I am not so sure what are you  trying to accomplish with the code you provided. Should there be a `GPS_thread.join()` before your script is terminated?

Comment: @barny - Have you Adafruit GPS module? Without this, you will not run my script.

Comment: @JasonLiu - with GPS_thread.join() nothing change.

Comment: Have you read the MCVE link? No I haven’t got a GPS, but the point of *”Minimal”* is that you put some effort into creating a small executable code example whih shows your problem so that people who might help you _can_ execute it and help you wth the problem, i.e. in this case, without a GPS. Or do you think the GPS is the problem? Does your thread execute at all? Does it exit cleanly? As your while loop never ends (no break statement) it’s suspicious that using join() your program exits.

Comment: Chances are your thread is throwing an exception - add a try/catch around the entire code in GPSThread which prints something then raises so overall behaviour is still the same.

Comment: @barny - I can print data normally, so thread is working. I did try/except but i didn't get any exception.

Comment: If your thread were working your overall program would pause forever and never exit on the join. Scatter print statements in the thread function, make sure it is starting, check if it is exiting. No-one else can debug your code except you.